# Querystring Route in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to create a route to a specific controller/action which needs to accept optional querystring parameters.

the urls i'd like to accept are:

```
/Products/ProductsListJson
/Products/ProductsListJson?productTypeId=1
/Products/ProductsListJson?productTypeId=1&brandId=2
/Products/ProductsListJson?productTypeId=1&brandId=2&year=2010
```

I have an action like this:

```
public JsonResult ProductsListJson(int productTypeId, int brandId, int year)
```

And a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null, "Products/ProductsListJson",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "ProductsListJson", productTypeId = 0, brandId = 0, year = 0 }
);
```

I assumed that the action "ProductsListJson" would simply see the querystring urls and map them to the appropriate arguments however this is not happening.

Anyone know how this could be achived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify their values in the route if those parameters are passed in the query string:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null, "Products/ProductsListJson",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "ProductsListJson" }
);
```

and your action:

```
public ActionResult ProductsListJson(int? productTypeId, int? brandId, int? year)
{
    ...
}
```

but you probably don't need a specific route for this as the default route will handle it just fine:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd like them to default to 0 automatically. Is that possible? Or do i need to evaluate in the action?

Comment: Well then simply use the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). Whenever you need to use them: `productTypeId ?? 0`

Comment: all good.. was hoping the route could handle that.. thanks for your help :)